# Remove word wrapping in Microsoft Word "Web Layout"

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I'd like to remove word wrapping in Microsoft Word, as one can do with Notepad.

Is there a way to remove the word wrap on the Web Layout of Microsoft Word?

Comment: Which version of Word do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncheck this check box:

`File` > `Options` > `Advanced` > `Show document content` > `Show text wrapped within the document window`

Comment: Sadly, it is already unchecked